# Auto Increment Alphabet in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me about this problem? I create an Auto Increment Alphabet in javascript but nothing happens if i click the button.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var test = 5;
    var b = String.fromCharCode(64 + parseInt(test.toString()));
    var a = String.fromCharCode(64 + 1);

    for (var i = a; i <= b.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text[i];
    };
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `var i = a` should be `var i = a.length`. Where is `text` defined?

Comment: You're passing `String.fromCharCode` a single value.  Therefore both `a` and `b` are strings of length 1.  You're doing a `for` loop with `i` equal to a string and checking for `i < = 1`.  *Why* do you have a `for` loop?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: `a` equals `A`, `for (var i="A" ...`

Comment: What they all said ^

Comment: what is the meaning of `parseInt(test.toString()` ??

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `text` is not defined in your code.

```js
var currentCode = 0;

function nextChar() {
    currentCode++;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(64 + currentCode);
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = character;
}

nextChar(); // Initialize with "A"
```

```html
<button onclick="nextChar()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt for you

```js
function myFunction() {
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);
        document.write(letter);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: @josephlumongtad You're most welcome, if it helped you get an answer I would be grateful if you accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

### Is this what you looking for :

```js
function myFunction() {
    var test = 5;
    var b = 64 + parseInt(test.toString());
    var a = 64 + 1;

    for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(i);
    };
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```